Escape character in keyboard macros
In earlier releases, up to 12.04 I think, it was possible to create a text file and insert the ESC character, then copy/paste the text into a text terminal and the escape character would function normally as the escape key .
Both insertion & copy/paste are done into the terminal which is running a text based database program (Dataflex/PFXPlus).
The escape character (27) is written to a text file on disk. The effect of the ESC key in the program is to back out one level out of of entry screens or menus.
Since at least 18.04, this doesn't work any more.
Is there a different way to achieve this?

How are you inserting the ESC character? Which program are you pasting the text into? Please [edit] your question to add whatever information you get. Do not use Add Comment.

Escape / control characters are deliberately filtered out when pasting, as a security measure. This was introduced in VTE in 2015. At least Xterm, and presumably more terminals out there also do this.
A small utility could invoke ioctl() with the TIOCSTI parameter to fake input into a tty line, one byte at a time.
It would be nice to hear what your actual problem is, to make sure we don't face an XY Problem. Maybe your actual use case has a more straightforward solution.

SOrry if not clear, but need to be able to paste the ESC character into the terminal, which now seems to be no longer possible

It's indeed no longer possible. If you really "need" to do this, you might want to patch VTE, or find another terminal emulator that allows you to do this. Or you might try to find a different workflow for your actual problem, one that doesn't rely on pasting the escape character.
